# Alarm not ringing in android

Tags: android

Hi 
In my android application i would like to set alarm for particular time.
I am using the below code.I am able to view the toast but no ring or alert is observed.
Could anyone please let me know if i can display the toast with an default alarm tone.

```
  int newAlarmPeriod = 15000; // For debugging  
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, GroupsCheckAlarmReceiver.class); 
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,alarmIntent, 0); 
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); 
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+ newAlarmPeriod, newAlarmPeriod, sender); 



public class GroupsCheckAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{   
@Override  
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {     
     Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm worked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    Log.d("XXX", "GroupsCheckAlarmReceiver.onReceive");   }
```

}

Do i need to set any manifest permissions except receiver registery.

Please share your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to add a standard `Notification` call as described in [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Sound) to your `GroupsCheckAlarmReceiver#onReceive` method.